# Exceção de Negocio não esta no classpath do ClientEJB

Tags: java, exceção, ejb

Tenho a seguinte situação:

**EJB PROJECT**

```
public BussinessException extends Exception {}

public MyInterfaceImplementation implements MyInterface {}
```

**EJB PROJECT CLIENT**

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void foo() throws BussinessException;    
}
```

Só que a exceção (`BussinessException`) nao esta no classpath do `EJBClient`.
Como resolver esse problema?? Não posso botar o projeto EJB (físico) no classpath do client.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do André (queria colocar como comentário). Segue um exemplo visual:

[image: diagrama]

Curiosamente, um usuário de outro forum fez uma pergunta parecida, e eu subi um projeto maven no github com uma estrutura parecida, para visualizar, [clique aqui](https://github.com/wryel/jboss-jee).

Answer (score 0):

Que tal três projetos?

- Projeto API: contém suas interfaces e exceções de negócio.
- Projeto EJB: implementa suas interfaces e depende do jar do Projeto API.
- Projeto Cliente: acessa o seu projeto EJB e também depende do jar do Projeto API.